# TextBlock Text Property only Binding once even Binding Mode Set to TwoWay

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Source Code:

```
class Cons
{
    public Cons()
    {
        BaseDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        SetProperty();
    }
    private void SetProperty()
    {
        NowPlaying = "Hello";
    }
    public string NowPlaying{get; set; }
}
public partial class MainWindow
{
    Cons Resources = new Cons()
    public MainWindow()
    {
         txbl.DataContext = Resources;
         Resources.NowPlaying = "NoHello";
    }
}
```

And a text block `<Textblock x:Name="txbl" Text="{Binding NowPlaying, Mode=TwoWay}"/>` 
When I set the NowPlaying Property in the MainWindow contructor, the Property changed to "NoHello", but the TextBlock Text Property still Hello even I set binding mode = TwoWay

The Image I Capture When the Problem Occured
[image]

Comment: I don't know what you  are doing wrong. I copied your code and it works fine. BTW you don't need  `binding mode = TwoWay` because the TextBlock can't be changed from the GUI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've mentioned works correctly. The textblock does show the new value "NoHello".
But, if you wish to update the the property value NowPlaying after your textblock has been loaded, please implement INotifyPropertyChanged on your class Cons and raise PropertyChanged in the setter of the property NowPlaying.

Comment: If I want to change property via Binding after the TextBlock is created then I need to use that Interface? I have changed the NowPlaying Property When the Event Occurred

Comment: Yes. Refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614(v=vs.85).aspx to implement it on your class.

Comment: Even I Add INotifyPropertyChanged Source [here](https://pastebin.com/MGJW2Mgf) but the it still not work

Comment: It works correctly in the code snippet you provided. There must be some other problem with the binding. Is workingResources the correct DataContext for the textblock?

Comment: @QuanVN You are passing the variable Nowplaying to NotifyPropertyChanged instead of the string with the name of the variable. Change that line to NotifyPropertyChanged("Nowplaying"), with quotes.